# Connecting a cash register to a bank terminal with LUA

Tags: lua, bank, verifone

I amdevelopping a script with LUA that have to make communication between a cash register and a bank terminal via TCP IP connection.

I would like to ask which TCP IP number port to mention in code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is almost certainly specific to the make and model of bank terminal you are using; you'll have to consult the manufacturer's documentation.

Comment: Thanks for yr reply. The model of bank terminal is Verifone Yonami using BBS Sofie Protocol. I searched on google but without finding any results.

Comment: Hmm, yes, documentation does seem a bit thin. It looks like other products integrate with that terminal (like [Lightspeed](https://retail-support.lightspeedhq.com/hc/en-us/articles/228842807-Setting-up-payment-processing-with-Worldline-s-Yomani-Yoximo-terminals-on-your-iPad), which uses port 9000, but it's not clear whether that's on the terminal or the iPad). Your best bet is probably to contact the manufacturer (Verifone or Worldline, depending on who's reselling from whom).

Comment: As a subnote, I'd also make this something that can be configured without adjusting the code, future IT will appreciate it!

Comment: Harry Cutts, I contacted the manufacturer 'Verifone', they told me that the communication could be done without mentioning the TCP/IP port. But I am unable to understand what value to put instead or how to process..(on the terminal bank, on TCP/IP settings there is the same thing :  Port TCP/IP with ECR is : without port)